# How can I do this sentence show me in arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

How can I do this sentence show me in arduino."WARNING: Category 'USB' in library Mouse/keyboard is not valid.Setting to 'Uncategorized'

Comment: Umm..... you what?

Comment: Your question does not make any sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.

Note that [Mouse and Keyboard libraries](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard) are suitable for use with Arduino Due and Zero boards, or with 32u4-based boards like Arduino Leonardo or Micro.   They are not relevant when using an Uno.

Comment: For Uno, it's LUFA: http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php